# Handling files with different structure For each Loop SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

There are 3 files in a directory and two of them are with same structure and the 3rd one has 3 more extra column in the end of the file.

```
file 1: columna,....,columnz 
file 2: columna,....,columnz 
file 3: columna,....,columnz,Column1,Column2,column3
```

Is it possible to import all these files using a single connection with in a for each loop container?
If the flat file connection  connection is  based on the file 3 .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No this is not possible in SSIS.  Using a Flat File Connection designed for file 3 will corrupt data loaded from files 1 & 2.

I would build 2 Flat File Connections for the different layouts, then within the For Each Loop Container I would build 2 Data Flow Tasks for the two layouts.  I would disable the Data Flow Tasks using an Expression, so that only the appropriate Data Flow Task executes against each file.

Comment: I didn't catch the last piece, can you please elaborate (I would disable the Data Flow Tasks using an Expression, so that only the appropriate Data Flow Task executes against each file)

Comment: I would set the Disable property on the Data Flow Tasks using an Expression. This assumes you have some way of identifying file 1 vs 2 & 3.  The Expression on the DFT for file 1 might read: `SUBSTRING ( @[User::MyFileName] , 1 , 5 ) != "file 1:"`

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do it is load each row in as one varchar column and split it afterward.

Answer (score 0):

i just had the same situation which i tried to make it in a similar way. Didn’t thought about adding expressions in Data Flow. So, i created 2 packages to deal with individual file structure managed by 1 master package.